# Is "to" really part of the infinitive?

Tags: grammar

Consider this:

> I **like to** eat here.

vs

> I **would** eat here.

It appears to me that "to" has nothing to do with the infinitive form of the verb that follows. It is, in this example,  an integral part of **like to**, not of **to eat**.

Is my thinking flawed? If you think it is, could you please explain which form of the verb "eat" is used in the second example, if not the infinitive?

Comment: Don't forget that "to" can even stand alone in uses reminiscent of pronouns: "Do you like to dance? I like to". And it has been merged into some very common colloquial contractions with the *preceding* verb rather than the *following* verb: "going to" -> "gonna", "want to" -> "wanna", "got to" -> "gotta".

Comment: "This" is no doubt indefinite pronoun reference, but I hope this helps answer the question, because "answer" is the infinitive and there isn't any "to" that is part of it. I like to think that the infinitive and the imperative have the same form; e.g., "Eat your spinach, because it's good for you to eat spinach." So I like to think of "to" as a preposition that often introduces an infinitive but is not a part of the infinitive it introduces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is probably a matter of definition, not of true inherent "belonging to". I believe the etymology of this kind of "to" is the usage of a preposition before the infinitive, in order to indicate a relation of direction or purpose between a finite verb and the infinitive: *I went to school; I went to pick him up*. This probably originated in predicates with verbs that have a direction. But that was long ago, when the infinitive still had a distinctive form in English or Proto-Germanic; I think it was something like **eatan* (don't pin me down on this, I haven't looked it up). Later, when the infinitive became indistinguishable from other forms of the verb, this *to* evolved into a more general marker of the infinitive. So the most precise definition would probably be to say that *to* belongs neither to the finite verb ("like") nor to the infinitive.

That said, you could say "*like* often goes with *to*, so we say *to* belongs to *like*", or "*to* often introduces or links to infinitives, so we say it belongs to the infinitive". In lists of phrases, educational books often tend to emphasise the connection with *like*; in passages that describe the infinitive, they tend to treat it as part of the "full" infinitive, as opposed to the "bare" infinitive in "I will go". I believe this is the most traditional way to describe it.

Comment: +1 Exactly - "to" *is* part of the infinitive, but only because that is what the word "infinitive" has been defined to mean :-)

Comment: Your etymology of the infinitive is correct. The proto-Germanic infinitive had no prefix, and the various daughter languages have used different function words to make infinitive prefixes: German "zu" and English "to" are cognate (word-initial /*t/ becomes /z/ in German), while Danish and Swedish have "at, and Norwegian has "å" (most likely descended from the same ancestor word as "og", the word for "and"). The OE infinitive is almost correct, my (Norwegian) etymological dictionary gives "etan" and proto-Germanic "etanam" (cognate Latin "edere" and Sanskrit "ad-").

Comment: @Arnsholt: Thank you. The suffix *-anam* makes sense, considering that Ancient Greek has *-ein* and *-nai*. Old Dutch has *-an*. P.S. If *og* is a cognate of Swedish *at*, could English *at* be a cognate of *and*? And are they all cognates of Latin *at*, "but"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "å" and "at" are not cognate. The words for "and" in Norwegian, Danish and Swedish are "og"/"og"/och", while "at" is a subordinator in all three languages. Latin "at" would be Norse "aþ", but it's "at" in Norse as well, but apparently it is cognate with Latin "ad" (according to Bokmålsordboka). Those Greek infinitives look like plausible cognates, but unfortunately I don't really know any Greek (and infinitives are a complicated matter). Vedic Sanskrit has several infinitives, but I don't have the books I need to see if there are any corresponding ones in Sanskrit ATM.

Comment: It seems Proto-Greek already had infinitive suffixes in *-ehen, -enai* and *-men*. A pity we don't know much about the infinitive in PIE.

Comment: @Cerberus PIE almost certainly didn't have infinitives; what it did have was various different ways of forming verbal nouns, which later came to function as infinitives in the daughter languages.

Comment: @arnsholt The infinitive marker in Scandiwegian (_å/at/att_) is entirely parallel to _to_ in English: it is the same preposition as _at_ in English (Dan. _ad_, Swe. _åt_, Icel. _að_) reduced to a short and frequently consonant-free [ɔ ~ a ~ ʌ]. _Og/och_ is unrelated, being instead related to the verb _øke/øge/öka/auka_ ‘increase’ (also _eke_ in English). The subordinator _at(t)_ is also unrelated, being an aphaeretised version of _þat_ ‘that’—it is thus completely parallel to _that_ in English, _dat_ in Dutch, and _dass_ in German. (And Sanskrit infinitives tend to be t-stems.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Oh, okay, but it did in Proto-Germanic, didn't it?

Comment: Yes, Proto-Germanic definitely had infinitives, most marked with _-*aną_ marker < PIE (thematic) _*-ó-no-m_. There were one or two athematic verbs still floating about which instead had just _*-ną_. The ending is probably ultimately a neuter nominalisation of the PIE verbal adjectives in _-*(o)-nó-_ which themselves became the past participles of strong verbs (_-en_ in English, as in _beaten_, etc.) and also appear in Greek as adjectives in _-νός_. (This in opposition to the more common PIE verbal adjectives in _*-tó-_ > weak participles in _-ed_, Greek _-τός_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Thanks for the overview, that all makes perfect sense! Is the Latin suffix *-nus* also related, as in *Victorinus, Traianus*? And the -nos in Greek medial participles? And the Greek infinite endings (what contradiction!)? I believe the Latin infinitive is from -se, so that is probably not related.

Comment: Probably, at least indirectly. The Greek middle participles are actually probably directly inherited from PIE _*-mh₁no-_ also found in Skt. _-māna-_. Some reconstruct this as just _*-mno-_, assuming it’s from the root _*men-_ ‘think, mind’, in which case there’s no relation; but most think of it as a _*-no_-extension to some _*meh₁-_ that we don’t quite know what is. Lat. _-nus_ is sometimes just _*-nó-_, and sometimes (esp. in _-ōnus_) from a thematicised [‘Hoffman suffix’ _*-h₃nh₂-o-_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-h₃onh₂-).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: OK so I suppose some parts of those etymologies are unclear, and the suffixes may or may not be related to some degree...

Answer (score 7):

Here are the two main bits of positive evidence that *to* is part of the infinitive.

**1. It doesn't show up with nouns in the same situations.**

> - I like to dance.
> - I like pizza.

Notice that *to* is not an inherent part of *like*, because even in the exact same sense of the word, if it is followed by a noun there is no *to*.

**2.  It shows up without another verb.**

In phrases without a verb in front of the *to*, you can see it appearing:

> - To live is to dance.

For modals, as others have explained, the modal verbs do something special with the verb, as do the helper verbs "to be" and "to have".  But they are a special case.  Modal verbs also don't allow a gerund after them in any situation, e.g., you can't say "*I would walking" like you can with a verb that is usually followed by *to*.  But with "like" you can say "I like to dance" and "I like dancing".  Only the form of the verb is changing, from the infinitive to the gerund.

Comment: +1, good examples. I am not so sure about "_is_ part of the infinitive" - although it appears that it certainly _was_ in the past. I will keep the current accepted answer as it appears to be more applicable to the modern form of English, although I'm probably not qualified to make that call...

Comment: @romkyns: Well, I'm not sure what makes you think this answer applies to something other than modern English.  Linguists certainly treat *to* as part of the infinitive, and the evidence I provide uses modern English to show that.

Comment: Someone has proposed a theory that I found quite compelling: that "to" evolved from a form of "do". "I like do dance" and "Do live is do dance" sounds at least somewhat plausible... Is this totally random and a complete coincidence? :)

Comment: What Romkyns said in their first comment. I have some intresting data for you though: 'We proceeded to the gate' versus 'We proceeded to dance'.

Answer (score 3):

The second sentence does use the infinitive, but *would* is a modal verb, so it kicks out the *to*. Wikipedia [explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb#Morphology_and_syntax):

> The main verb that is modified by the modal verb is in the infinitive form and is not preceded by the word *to* (German: *zu*, Dutch: *te*). There are verbs that may seem somewhat similar in meaning to modal verbs (e.g. *like*, *want*), but the construction with such verbs would be different

Note how you wouldn't say "*I can to eat here" or "*I must to eat here", either.

Comment: So this also suggests that "to" is not an integral part of the infinitive, right?

Comment: Sticking with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#English), "In English, a verb's infinitive is its unmarked form, such as *be*, *do*, *have*, or *sit*, often introduced by the particle *to*. When this particle is absent, the infinitive is said to be a *bare infinitive*; when it is present, it is generally considered to be a part of the infinitive, then known as the *full infinitive* (or *to-infinitive*)."

Comment: Huh, because I didn't think the second sentence used the infinitive, but "She would eat here." obviously does use the infinitive, not "She would eats here."

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. This is probably one of the biggest misconceptions in all of English grammar/linguistics.

The bare infinitive *IS* the infinitive.

It's better to say that "to" *accompanies* the infinitive depending on how it is used, but it's not part of the infinitive nor does it complete the infinitive.

When the infinitive is used as an adjunct or a complement of another word, it cannot be used alone. It's needs the grammatical particle in between to "bind it", so to speak, to the word that it's complementing. This has parallels in many other languages:

> something **to** eat
>
> quelque chose **à** manger.
>
> algo **para** comer
>
> etwas **zu** essen

In the example you gave above, you are correct. To, in that context, is part of the phrase "like to", which is an auxiliary with the same grammatical function as 'would'. In compound verbs with modal auxiliaries the bare infinitive is used.