# What part of speech is "to" when attached to an infintive?

Tags: infinitives, parts-of-speech

For example, in "to see", what part of speech is "to"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is “to” really part of the infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9400/is-to-really-part-of-the-infinitive)

Comment: The only part of that question which answers this question is [Reg's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9400/is-to-really-part-of-the-infinitive#comment15568_9403).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Agreed. Altough even that doesn't really answer the question either. It just says what people call the two words together...